# show two texts for one mouseOver event

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap

I am trying to display two different texts on one mouseover event.
I added different id's to two functions.

```
<script>
    function writeText2(txt) {
        document.getElementById("earth").innerHTML = txt;
    };

    function writeText(txt) {
        document.getElementById("venus").innerHTML = txt;
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<img src ="test.png" alt="planet" usemap="#planet" />
<map name="planet">
<p id="earth"></p>
    <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213
"href="#"; title="Learn" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText2('earth'); 
writeText('venus')" onmouseout="writeText2(''); writeText('')"/> 
</map>
```

I gave both #venus and #earth some CSS styling to display them on different positions but somethow I can only see the 'earth' appear on mouseover.

I thought it might be because the `<p>` only has the id earth but I am not sure how to add another id here?

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Here is a simplified  example of what I am trying to achieve (the black arrow presents the mouse)
[image: Example]

Comment: Please format your code, and why is there a semicolon in your tag attribute list?

Comment: Why don't you create a single function that calls both functions? Also, where is Venus? I don't even see it.

Comment: @Rika You need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hstjs1k1/1/

Comment: @Rika check my new answer is http://jsfiddle.net/hstjs1k1/10/ this what you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears that you are implementing a solution for maybe a tooltip? Looks like you have stumbled upon this tutorial: [w3shools: HTML <area> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp).

What you already have just needs to be modified as such.

```js
var planets = [ 'mercury', 'venus' ];

function showTooltips(selectedPlanet) {
  for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
    var planet = planets[i];
    var el = getEl(planet);
    writeText(el, planet);
    if (planet === selectedPlanet) {
      addClass(el, 'current');
    }
  }
}

function clearTooltips() {
  for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
    var el = getEl(planets[i]);
    writeText(el, '');
    removeClass(el, 'current');
  }
}

function writeText(el, txt) {
  el.innerHTML = txt;
}

function getEl(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.className.indexOf(className) == -1) {
    el.className += ' ' + className;
  }
}

function removeClass(el, className){
  var elClass = el.className;
  while (elClass.indexOf(className) != -1) {
    elClass = elClass.replace(className, '');
    elClass = elClass.trim();
  }
  el.className = elClass;
}
```

```css
.hover-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
#mercury {
  left: 80px;
  top: 36px;
}
#venus {
  left: 120px;
  top: 30px;
}
.current {
  color: #FFAA00;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/sun.gif" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm"
        onmouseover="showTooltips('mercury')"
        onmouseout="clearTooltips()" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm"
        onmouseover="showTooltips('venus')"
        onmouseout="clearTooltips()" />
</map>

<p class="hover-text" id="mercury"></p>
<p class="hover-text" id="venus"></p>
```

Comment: Okay but this shows different texts on two different mouseover areas. I want to show two texts when hovering over the same area. The texts will be displayed for example top left and bottom left at the same time.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you want accomplished? That would be easier. Just use MS Paint or something...

Comment: Yes, I added a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks so much. I think this should do it and I can work with that.

Answer (score 1):

The function "getElementById()" finds an element with the specified id.  Since there is no element with the id of "venus", your writetext() function does nothing. You seem to be aware of this, which is why you ask how to add another id.

An element can only have one id, but there are lots of other ways to find a particular element.  However, if you find the same element and set its text twice, the second time will just override the first time.

The most straight-forward way to accomplish what you seem to be attempting is to simply add another element and give it the id of venus.

If you really want a single element to have both strings in its innerHTML attribute, you will need to append the second string, instead of setting the attribute.

Added:

I'm not familiar with the area tag, but it would seem you could just add another paragraph element with the id of venus:

```
<map name="planet">
<p id="earth"></p>
<p id="venus"></p>
    <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213
"href="#"; title="Learn" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText2('earth'); 
writeText('venus')" onmouseout="writeText2(''); writeText('')"/> 
</map>
```

Comment: Do you know an example where another element and id was added? I have trouble getting it to work

Comment: Thanks for reiterating what I said in the comments... :-p

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/hstjs1k1/10/

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('.mapping').mouseover(function() {
    $("#mytext").append($(this).attr('planet-name')+ " : " +$(this).attr('custom-text1')+ "" +$(this).attr('custom-text1')+'<br>');
    //alert();

}).mouseout(function(){
    $("#mytext").empty();
});
 });


    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" custom-text1="custom1.1" custom-text2="custom1.2" planet-name="Sun" class="mapping" href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/sun.gif" />
    <p id="mercury"></p>
    <area shape="circle" custom-text1="custom1.1" custom-text2="custom1.2" coords="90,58,3" class="mapping" planet-name="Mercury" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm"/>
    <p id="venus"></p>
    <area shape="circle" custom-text1="custom2.1" custom-text2="custom2.2" coords="124,58,8" planet-name="Venus" class="mapping" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm" />
</map>
    <div id="mytext" style="border:1px;">This will change</div>
```

Comment: The solution is OK but just missed onmouseout event

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but somehow nothing is appears on mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Just use on function like that:

```
      function writeText() {
var txt1 = 'textOne';
var txt2 = 'textTwo'; 
          document.getElementById("earth").innerHTML = txt1;
          document.getElementById("venus").innerHTML = txt2;

            };
     function deletText() {

var txt1 = '';
var txt2 = ''; 
          document.getElementById("earth").innerHTML = txt1;
          document.getElementById("venus").innerHTML = txt2;
}



            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <img src ="test.png" alt="planet" usemap="#planet" />
        <map name="planet">
        <p id="earth"></p>
            <area shape="poly" coords="174,361,149,350,180,203,217,213
        "href="#"; title="Learn" alt="Shop Now" onmouseover="writeText();" onmouseout="deleteText();"/> 
        </map>
```

Comment: It displays 'textOne' on the bottom of the page but nothing when I hover over the area